# Multiline graph throws parse error on already parsed dates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a multiline graph based on mbostock's example (see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955). However, I hit a wall when I try rendering the paths, since D3js is throwing me an error about not being able to parse a date, even though the dates have already been parsed. I put my code on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/iwOVIce/1/edit

Does anyone know what the issue is here? I've looked over the example dozens of times but can't seem to find what's causing the error. Thank in you advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I declared the Y domain wrong, changing my code from

```
y.domain(d3.extent($scope.dataset, function (d) {
  return d.amount;
})).nice();
```

to

```
y.domain([
    d3.min(sources, function (s) {
      return d3.min(s.values, function (v) {
        return v.amount;
      });
    }),
    d3.max(sources, function (s) {
      return d3.max(s.values, function (v) {
        return v.amount;
      });
    })
  ]);
```

did the trick.